# WebView open webpage, links when clicked show "Web page not available"

Tags: android, android-webview, webviewclient

This approach works fine with other web pages, except this [one](https://omega.ffzg.hr/). Results are the same with WebChromeClient, and with android:hardwareaccelerated="true", as suggested on some other question on SO.

These 4 just keep on repeating in Eclipse LogCat...

```
Unknow chromium error: -337, 
Could not parse Spdy Control Frame Header,
Recived data frame for invalid stream 15,
external/chromium/net/spdy_session.cc:1058: [0939/183331:WARNING:spd]
```

Here is my source code...

```
package com.mypackage.pk;
import com.mypackage.pk.R;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class F1Activity extends DashboardActivity 
{
    private WebView webView;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView (R.layout.activity_f3);
    setTitleFromActivityLabel (R.id.title_text);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView5);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.loadUrl("https://omega.ffzg.hr/");

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
        {

            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

    });
}   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that's because that URL is https.  Here's a blog about how to handle it:

http://damianflannery.wordpress.com/2010/09/28/android-webview-with-https-loadurl-shows-blankempty-page/

Comment: These 4 just keep on repeating in Eclipse LogCat...

Unknow chromium error: -337, 
Could not parse Spdy Control Frame Header,
Recived data frame for invalid stream 15,
external/chromium/net/spdy_session.cc:1058: [0939/183331:WARNING:spd]